# Write to CSV and correct displaying in Excel 2010-2012

Tags: c#, excel, cvs

Help me please write every value to different cell, I try to write data in the CSV file but when I open this file in Excel the value showing in one line (cell). Did different various separators between the values "." and ",". But the results in Office 2010 and 2012 the same... And one more interesting think, in Office 2007 that work's with (*.xls)...

```
string s = "";
s += "Nick-Name, Category, Web-Pages, ICQ, Skype, Mail, Phone\r";
for (int i = 0; i < listOfUsers.Count; i+=3)
{
   s += nickName[i] + "," + category[i] + "," + webList[i] + "," + ICQList[i] + "," + skypeList[i] + "," + mailList[i] + "," + phoneList[i] + ";\r";
}
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"" + folder + "Parse_people_list.csv", s, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

[image: P1]
<sub>(source: [pixs.ru](http://i7.pixs.ru/storage/8/8/6/page1JPG_7902893_11519886.jpg))</sub>

[image: P2]
<sub>(source: [pixs.ru](http://i6.pixs.ru/storage/9/1/3/page2JPG_5395108_11519913.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Can you paste the exact contents of the CSV (as it appears in a text editor)? Also, you should Environment.NewLine for newlines in C#. Also, You should really use a stringbuilder to build up such a massive string, as it will execute much quicker. You can use StringBuilder.AppendLine() which will append the text to the builder and add the new line.

Comment: @StealthRabbi [P1] http://i6.pixs.ru/storage/6/8/7/page3JPG_6384597_11520687.jpg this is text result from notepad. Tried StringBuilder.AppendLine() result the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try delimiting with tabs instead - Excel handles tab-delimited data better than comma-delimited since commas within the data may cause issues.

You can also use `StringBuilder.AppendLine` to improve performance and avoid adding line breaks manually:

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
s.AppendLine("Nick-Name\tCategory\tWeb-Pages\tICQ\tSkype\tMail\tPhone");
for (int i = 0; i < listOfUsers.Count; i+=3)
{
   s.AppendLine(
        nickName[i]  + "\t"
      + category[i]  + "\t"
      + webList[i]   + "\t"
      + ICQList[i]   + "\t"
      + skypeList[i] + "\t"
      + mailList[i]  + "\t"
      + phoneList[i]);;
}
```

Comment: and how correct to Out this file, tell me please? :\ System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"" + folder + "Parse_people_list.csv", ? , System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

Comment: Try saving is as a `TXT` file instead of `CSV`.

Comment: Also are you intentionally outputting every 3rd user?

Comment: Resolved this probleb like this... s += nickName[i] + ";" + category[i] + ";" + webList[i] + ...